# How to generate a 1 minute long mp3 file with a bump of frequency change in 5s?

Tags: mp3

I'm looking for a software that would help me to generate a 1 minute mp3 file with a bump of frequency change (like a blip sound) in an interval of 5s. Can Audacity do that?

Answer (score 3):

Use the click track plugin in audacity with a tempo of 12 bpm.
This link: [Click track plugin](http://manual.audacityteam.org/man/Click_Track)
and then export to mp3.